# Why is my recursive function not working when used within a loop?

Tags: php, recursion

I have a database that stores how users were referred into the system like so:

```
| user_id | referrer_id |
| 3       | 2           |
| 4       | 3           |
| 5       | 3           |
| 6       | 4           |
| 7       | 4           |
| 8       | 5           |
| 9       | 5           |
| 10      | 6           |
| 11      | 10          |
| 12      | 10          |
```

and I would like to display a specific user's network, i.e., the user, the other users which s/he referred directly, and also other users referred by the direct referrals, in an array.

So far, I've been able to create a recursive function

```php
// The actual get_downlines() function
function get_downlines($upline_id) {
    // Init the UsersMatrix model
    $um_model = model('UsersMatrix');
    $um_model->select('user_id')->where('upline_id', $upline_id);
    $downlines_check = $um_model->findAll(5);
    $downlines = [];
    if ( ! empty($downlines_check) ) {
        foreach($downlines_check as $check) {
            $downlines[] = $check->user_id;
        }
    }

    return $downlines;
}

// User to check
$user = 3;

// The initial network array
$network_array['user_network'][0] = [
    'id' => $user,
    'text' => "user-$user"
];

// Get the user's network
function get_network($referrer, $network_array){
    // This function basically runs a SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE referrer_id = $referrer_id
    // and returns the user_ids in an array: get_downlines()
    $downlines = get_downlines($referrer);
    if (count($downlines) > 0){
        // Loop through the downlines
        foreach($downlines as $downline){
            // Update the array
            array_push($network_array['user_network'], [
                'id' => $downline,
                'text' => "user-$downline",
            ]);

            // Check for the downlines of this user and inner levels
            get_network($downline, $network_array);
        }
    }

    // Return the network array
    return $network_array;
}
```

With this, I expect that when I run the `get_network(3, $network_array);`, I should get an array like so:

```php
Array
(
    [user_network] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [text] => user-3
                ),
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [text] => user-4
                ),
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [text] => user-5
                ),
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [text] => user-6
                ),
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [text] => user-7
                ),
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [text] => user-8
                ),
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [text] => user-9
                ),
            [7] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [text] => user-10
                )

        )

)
```

instead, the page dies with a maximum execution time error. But if I use a user ID without an indirect referrer, it works well. E.g user id 10.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you need to add a stop condition where you can terminate the recursion. Currently, it seems that it is running infinitely as there is no stop condition.

Comment: Also, this could potentially cause a lot of queries to run, I would solve this on the SQL end by using recursive SQL. The query might be somewhat harder, but it should be more performant.

Comment: The data is not real, isn't it? It can be infinite if you have `user_id=2, ref_id=3` and `user_id=3, ref_id=2`. Also you should pass the second array as reference, otherwise you won't get all ids.

Comment: @shingo, the data is real. Based on the structure, a `referrer_id` is an existing user and the data is stored upon registration.

Comment: @dev_mustafa, I had the stop condition in mind where I have `if (count($downlines) > 0)`. At least, it should get to a stage where the `$downlines` will be equal to `0`.

Comment: I don't see anything logically wrong with the recursion. This makes me want to see your DB calls. Are you reusing the same DB connection? Or creating new connections each time? Are you closing the connections properly? What is the max number of connections set to on your DB?

Comment: If so, I can't reproduce the error, [try it yourself](https://onlinephp.io?s=fVLtaoMwFP2t4DtcikyFDLRf2-jaPYiIpG1sw0qUGOlG6bsvuRqnruz-Med47r05h7x_VOfKcz3XP1JFYQup5zpz2O4gXWREnxd4XhJYIVwiXBN4QbhC-ErgDeEaYRIjSOIWJQSSuWGyjVlUNOKgeCngxFR-LK_iwgWrQ19GnnvTbadLuacXwPvoBocXIa9rpkJkUl9mkVY6jmSqkQJ61mg7LjXgjq4EU9dSfuZUSvqdBk3NZN5xQZbGWesYdAX8GJgL-0ZDOk6xL4XszLDP-G_20Ek3VPtgBZNSj4Cn8fbo1g71e9N6-TSErjnatFpeQHgoG2HcW1UEO4jtMFNFKRk9nAcSoPXvmqHUFF4mr5pad_wbD7HRDKuPyY4nDzTT2Kx2NhFn1qetUZL9BpgEOWi6t8fuY9_ESG7fQiW5ULkMhzsWf2ZHmx8%2C&v=8.1.14).

Comment: Maybe the sql queries or other codes spend too much time.

Comment: @DSander, Yes, I'm using the same DB connection. In fact, I'm using the latest CodeIgniter 4 framework.

Comment: Show me get_downlines() - Also how big of a dataset are you working with? How many records?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the actual `get_downlines()` function. And for now, I'm just testing with 10 records, which makes me wonder why the code doesn't run properly.

Comment: I am not intimately familiar with CodeIgniter 4, but seeing model() being instantiated multiple times for each iteration of your recursion looks bad to me. Especially when you are not supplying a namespace with your model name which forces CI to search all namespaces to find the one you are looking for. I can't imagine that being a good thing. Maybe check if $um_model is not null and only instantiate if it is. Or move initialization out of get_downlines().

Comment: You can have a look at the following DB fiddle for how to do this with recursive SQL: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bvtFcVrfXXQJnDppeJ6Jg5/3

Comment: @Samuel Asor did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @DSander, yes, I did try your suggestion, but unfortunately, I still get the same problem. The only working solution is using recursive SQL.